# DJANGO 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have been trying to **update** and **add** `+ 1` in the database model (sessions) field whenever a button is being **clicked**. I am trying to be able to add `+1` in a database field whenever a user clicks on a button and have that `+1` record and time when the button was clicked in an HTML table, Thank You All, Much Appreciate

**Views.py**

```
@admin_only
@api_view(['POST'])
def swimmersUpdate(request, pk):
    swimmers = Swimmers.objects.get(id=pk)
    cs = swimmers.sessions
    swimmers.sessions = cs + 1

    serializer = SubSerializer(instance=cs, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
    return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

***Serializers.py***

```
class SubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Swimmers
        fields ='__all__'
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('apiurls/', views.apiurls, name='apiurls'),
path('swimmers-list/', views.swimmersList, name='swimmers-list'),
path('swimmers-details/<int:pk>', views.swimmersDetails, name='swimmers-details'),
path('swimmers-create/', views.swimmersCreate, name='swimmers-create'),
path('swimmers-update/<int:pk>', views.swimmersUpdate, name='swimmers-update'),
path('swimmers-delete/<int:pk>', views.swimmersDelete, name='swimmers-delete'),
```

**Models.py**

```
class Swimmers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    idno = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    sessions = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    totalsessions = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True )
    dateofpayment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)
    date_from = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_to = models.DateField(null=True)
    type_choice = (
        ("basic", "Basic"),
        ("3x1 week", "3x1 Week"),
        ("1 session", "1 Session"),
        ("2x1", "2x1"),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True, 
        choices=type_choice, default=type_choice)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=True)
    registration = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    keenphone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: `SubSerializer(instance=swimmers, data=request.data)`

Comment: if i set the instance as swimmers the i could update the data but the + 1 function is not working

Comment: it's not working because you have to call save after `swimmers.sessions = cs + 1`... `swimmers.save()` and then pass it through your serializer